# UICollectionView moves super view when calling cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation

I have a view that is placed outside the screens bounds (beneath). When a button is pushed this view is animated up, so that it becomes visible. It sort of acts like a keyboard, although it isn´t.
Inside this view I have a container view which is hooked up to a UICollectionViewController.

The problems occurs when I scroll its collectionView. As soon as cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, the entire super view is moved outside the screen again (without animation). If I push the button again it animates back up.

Does anyone know what is causing this behavior? I suspect that the frames of the reused cells are sort of pushing the super view back to where it was initialized. Any suggestions how I should resolve this?

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: Yes, and everything is laid out in IB with constraints. When the view controller which holds everything is loaded, the view that I am animating is actually set up with a frame that is visible. And when viewDidLayoutSubviews is called I move it out of the way so it is hidden.

Comment: but for animating the view, are you modifying the constraints? or you use setFrame?

Comment: I only change the frame. I don´t really get any errors regarding constraints that are broken or similar. But do you think this may be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using autolayout, you should animate using constraints. I had this same issue before. Maybe `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times while you are using the app, and hides your view again.

Comment: Thanks, viewDidLayoutSubviews was called multiple times. I will look into animation with constraints.